# Is this the right way to get string resources from within a Fragment?

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, android-resources, android-context

Which method is generally better / safer for reading string resources while in a Fragment?

Here I read `getResources().getString()` directly:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static SomeFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String someString = getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_id);
    }

}
```

Or is it better to do it this way, by setting a Context field first and then reading the resources from that:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;

    public static SomeFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String someString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_id);
    }

}
```

Any tradeoffs/drawbacks to either of these methods?

The reason I ask is because sometimes I've run into nullpointer issues with the first approach that were resolved by using the second approach; so I wasn't sure if it was problematic to use the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach is more complicated and adds no value over the first approach. Use the first approach.

Comment: The reason I ask is because sometimes I've run into nullpointer issues with the first approach that were resolved by using the second approach; so I wasn't sure if it was problematic to use the first one.

Comment: @KaliMa: If you run into a `NullPointerException` requesting a resource, your problem is that you are requesting the resource at an inappropriate time, when the fragment is not attached to an activity. Your workaround, if it changes that behavior, is introducing a memory leak, as you are holding onto some former `Context` when you should not be doing so anymore.

Comment: Is it generally safe to call during the onCreate / onCreateView methods?

Comment: @KaliMa: If you mean *directly* in those methods, yes. However, if you fork a thread from those methods, and you are attempting to access resources (or anything else tied to the hosting activity) in that thread, you can get yourself in trouble with this sort of problem.

Comment: What about holding a reference to the application object that has an exposed Context getter (i.e. the application context)? Initialized in the Fragment's `onCreate()` via something like `myApp = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication();`

Comment: @KaliMa: The `Application` singleton is safe to hold onto, as it it a singleton and cannot be leaked further. Note that the `Application` knows nothing about your theme, and so using it to retrieve resources that might be adjusted based on theme will not work.

Comment: By "theme" does this also imply language / locale? (the string resource I am retrieving may be different in different languages)

Comment: @KaliMa: No. By theme I mean theme, as identified by `android:theme` attributes in your manifest. A theme defines the look and feel of your UI. It is possible, though uncommon, for a theme to specify different string resources, and so using `Application` for string resources should be OK. However, do not use it for inflating a layout, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches are better. No issues in this. You faced the null pointer exception because.

When a fragment transaction happens the lifecycle of the fragment starts and only when it gets attached to the activity and when reaches the onstart it will be ready.

Some times if we try to access the public methods of the fragment immediately after the fragmentManager's commit. Then you will run into null pointer exception while accessing the context object. As it is not still completed the process.

So its developers logic to write the code understanding the life cycle to avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

When Fragments is onCreate() method, it already has the Activity's context, so it is not necessary set the context previously. Unless you need to do an specific (and inusual) implementation of Context, like parsing variables/values from portrait screen mode to landscape mode I guess...

However you're getting an string resource from last context, wich is already set up, so well the parsed variables/values indeed.